# Travis CI cannot connect to http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/

Tags: wordpress, svn, travis-ci

I am running the command in Travis CI:

```
svn co --quiet http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/ /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes
```

but it failed with this message:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes': could not connect to server (http://develop.svn.wordpress.org)
```

You can see example in [this build](https://travis-ci.org/barzik/wp-tutorial-maker/jobs/80192145)

This command worked before, just before couple of days with the same build. see [this successful build](https://travis-ci.org/barzik/wp-tutorial-maker/jobs/80191835) for example - line 131.

What can I do? I don't have any issues with running this command locally and I don't know any other updated WordPress repository that I can rely on.

Comment: I've been having the same issue since last night

Comment: same here... I think it's safe to assume there's nothing wrong with our repositories, something must be wrong with wp's servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a timeout issue, not related to my code.
Here is an issue opened on it on [Travis Github](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4832). In the next time, I will know that there is an issue tracker there and will use it. If you stumble on this question with a connection issue (timeout) that is NOT occurring on your local machine, checking there is a good idea.