# Travis-CI and develop.github.wordpress.org timeout

Tags: wordpress, git, travis-ci

I have a Github repo for a WordPress theme, and for some time now I've been using the Travis-CI build system. This is primarily to check that all the pull requests being received, is under WordPress coding standards.

This worked just fine, right up until recently, when I get a timeout against develop.git.wordpress.org. I get ping reply to this host from my local machine:

```
PING develop.git.wordpress.org (66.155.40.244): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 66.155.40.244: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=184.963 ms
```

As it has suddenly stopped working, and I have made no changes in travis.yml, I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

[Here is the Travis-CI build error](https://travis-ci.org/olefredrik/FoundationPress/jobs/81161725)

[And here is the Github repository](https://github.com/olefredrik/foundationpress)

Any tips on how I can fix this, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a global issue regarding connection of Travis CI to WordPress, see [My question on it and the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665057/travis-ci-cannot-connect-to-http-develop-svn-wordpress-org-trunk-tests-phpunit)

Comment: It appears to be working again now. I also posted an issue on the Travis-CI repo at Github. [Here are the answers I got](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4832)